# What is the version of experience manager and workflow in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, cme, experience-manager, workflow

We can see different modules/products of SDL Tridion are having specific version associated with it. What is there version for Workflow and Experience Manager is in Tridion 2013 SP1?

Comment: Not sure I understand, as workflow and Experience Manager are _bundled_ with Tridion 2013 SP1. So their versions are 2013 SP1 (7.1 internally).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDL Tridion includes both Experience Manager and Workflow as part of the "SDL Tridion Core", so these are not different releases (like you would have with add-ons like SmartTarget).

For both of those modules, their version is the same as SDL Tridion, "SDL Tridion 2013 SP1", and they're both installed with the main Tridion installer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still want to get the versions of various SDL Tridion modules (added along with SDL Tridion or as a separate installer), you may want to navigate to the below path in the Windows Registry *(type regedit in `Start -> Run`)*:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Tridion
```

You can find internal versions of each installed module (Like Experience Manager but not feature of CMS like workflow) here as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: BTW, 7.1 = 2013 SP1

Comment: Just wanted to share the path of Registry from where all versions can be confirmed